# I can't find the markup for webpart properties in visual studio

Tags: 2013, visual-studio, visual-web-part, properties, custom-properties

I've created a custom web part editor but I don't know where to look if I want to find the markup for all the properties of my webpart inside visual studio. I mean I can create new controls on CreateChildControls() but I can't find the markup that generates the properties anywhere?

To make things clear. I'm looking to find the html for the properties so that I can change them a little. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

We have webpartname.webpart (an xml file) where you can find some of the default webpart property. If you want your custom property then you need to write it. Visit MSDN to know more.

[MSDN Creating a Web Part with Custom Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd584174%28v=office.11%29.aspx)